# Zero out a value

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that will allow me to enter a value in minutes and the program will output those minutes as the sum of days, hours and minutes between them.
For example if I input 10000 minutes I should get the output, "10000 minutes is 6 days, 22 hours and 40 minutes"). This is how much I have now:

```
min = int(input("Enter a whole number of minutes: "))
days = min/1440
remainday = min%1440
print (days)
```

I'm only having one problem asides from it being unfinished, if the user inputs a number of minutes under 1440 then i get a decimal answer for the number of days (which is expected) but if the number of minutes is not sufficient to make a day, then I want the it to say "0 days" not ".153 days". How would I zero out the value for days in such a case?

Comment: `min` is a built-in function in Python.  Use a different variable name like `mins`.  `divmod` is the built-in function you want to get integer dividends and remainders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Python 3 so the operator `/` is [true division, not integer division](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

You can either use floor division which is similar to Python 2's integer division:

```
days = min//1440
```

Or use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) to get both with a single command:

```
days, remaindays = divmod(min,1440)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use floor division (using a double `//` instead of a single `/` when dividing), which rounds down to the nearest integer:

```
min = int(input("Enter a whole number of minutes: "))
# Example input: 1000
days = min // 1440
remainday = min%1440
print (days)
# Output:
# 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to round **down** the result of the division (quotient) to the nearest integer. 
This can be done in many ways:

```
days = int(min/1440)
```

Or

```
days = min//1440 # // is the integer division in Python 3, while / is float division`
```

Or

```
days = math.floor(min/1440) # after importing "math" module, using "import math"
```